# Why do I have 2 similar packages installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-install

```
npm list js-yaml

+-- gulp-cssnano@2.1.3
| `-- cssnano@3.10.0
|   `-- postcss-svgo@2.1.6
|     `-- svgo@0.7.2
|       `-- js-yaml@3.7.0
`-- gulp-imagemin@6.2.0
  `-- imagemin-svgo@7.0.0
    `-- svgo@1.3.2
      `-- js-yaml@3.13.1
```

- Why do I have 2 similar packages installed?
- Why do they have a different version?
- How do I locate them in node_modules? (I can find **js-yaml@3.7.0** but
  not **js-yaml@3.13.1** in the node_modules directory)

Answer (score 1):

Why do I have 2 similar packages installed?
Why do they have a different version?

`js-yaml` is dependency for different versions of `svgo@0.7.2` and `svgo@1.3.2`. And both are using different versions of `js-yaml`. That is why two.

How do I locate them in node_modules? (I can find js-yaml@3.7.0 but not js-yaml@3.13.1 in the node_modules directory)

You will find it in `svgo`'s node_modules directly. Read more here - https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders.html

Comment: I find **js-yaml v.3.7.0** in `node_modules/svgo/node_modules/js-yaml` but I find **js-yaml v.3.13.1** in `node_modules/imagemin-svgo/node_modules/js-yaml`. So for **js-yaml@3.13.1** not in the svgo's node modules. And I'm not sure why.

Comment: it all depends on what all packages have you got installed which has `js-yaml` as their dependency.